# Import classes from playground into xcode project

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-playground

I currently have a xcode project, which has playgrounds within them. This is mainly to give developers a preview of what programmatic controls look like. All logic for these components has been separated into different swift files within the Sources folder which is nested within the playground.

The only issue I'm having is that i'm unable to actually import and use any of these classes within my xcode project. This is causing me to create duplicates of the classes outside of this playground, which isn't maintainable obviously.... So I was curious is it possible to include and import classes from your playground into your Xcode project?

I currently am working with the following structure[image: File structure]

Comment: Maybe you can set `public` key to your playground class and then you can use it.

Comment: @EmreCiftci I have tried making the classes both public and open and still the same result